# remote Layout cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In ASP.NET MVC one can use following property to assign a local layout page:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

With local I mean that it needs to reside in the same ASP.NET MVC project.

In our project we need to be able to share one layout page accross different solutions which are deployed by different teams at different times. So we need to be able to assign a layout page from a central location at runtime.
We don't want anybody to have to get the latest layout page and put it in their projects + deploy.

It is not possible to assign a remote URL to the layout property (which seems logical).
Has anybody ever tried something like this?

I was thinking of making an alternative Layout extension method which does the following (e.g. this.SetRemoteLayout("[url]"):

- synchronous well cached http request to fetch the layout page from a central web application
- downloading the layout page locally so that it can be accessed with the relative path e.g. "~/Views/Temp/_Layout.cshtml"
- Internally assigning the Layout property with the relative path of the downloaded file

Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: I think you could add a "fake" _layout to your project, then create an `pre-build` event that copies the "real" _layout over the fake one from your desired location.

Comment: Also, you can use a linked folder using the "mklink" command "mklink -d projectfolder canonicalfolder" (or even just link to the file itself).  This could, however, create issues in your source-control management; you'd probably want to ignore the linked content except in the canonical project.

Comment: The requirements define that it need to be at runtime. If layout changes occur the goal is that not all the projects need to be rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to follow next pattern:

- A central DLL is installed in the GAC with HTML helpers (managed by frameworking team)
- A local layout page (managed by normal teams) will call a html helper to render the entire layout
- We will define/render the generic sections within the html helpers

==> If the layout needs to change the central DLL html helper code is adapted and deployed. All applications are then automatically using the updated layout without having to redeploy their applications.

This is how we can define sections within html helpers:

```
    public static IHtmlString RenderSectionCustom(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        WebViewPage page = html.ViewDataContainer as WebViewPage;
        var section = page.RenderSection("CustomTop", false);
        return section == null ? MvcHtmlString.Empty : MvcHtmlString.Create(section.ToHtmlString());
    }

    public static IHtmlString DefineSectionCustom(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        WebViewPage page = html.ViewDataContainer as WebViewPage;

        page.DefineSection("CustomTop", () =>
        {
            page.Write(MvcHtmlString.Create(" hello world (custom top section from HTML HELPER)!"));
        });

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
```